# macOS app help document file folder disappeared

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to build the help file for a macOS app.

I imported .help folder to resources

[image]

the content of title file index.html is

[image]

items in info.plist file related help file

[image]

built my app content resource folder

[image]

it looks like the builder only keeps the index.html and removes the folder .help

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try removing the `.help` folder and adding it again. It should appear as a single object (bundle), and not as folder (and definitely not as a project folder which are just containers for assets, like a loose `index.html` file).

What you want is the the entire `.help` folder as a single asset that gets copied to your finished application bundle. It should look like an opaque item in Xcode:

[image]

Then in your application's build phase setting, the entire `.help` folder should be copied, as a single entity, to the app's resources:

[image]

If you have individual `.html` or other help files included in any of the build phases, or selected as members of a target, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

> I imported .help folder to resources

Incorrectly. You imported it as a group. You should have imported it as a folder reference.